# Vue.js How to add new property to a repeated array object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

html

```
<div v-repeat=dudes>{{a}}, {{b}}</div>
```

js

```
dudes = [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}]

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {dudes: dudes}
})
dudes[0].b = 'test'
```

Trying to set `dudes[0].b = 'test'` doesn't work.

http://jsbin.com/dogadutiqa/1/edit

Unless I define dudes with a `b` property to begin with `dudes = [{a:1, b:null}, {a:2}, {a:3}]`

How do I add new properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the limitations of ES5, Vue cannot detect properties directly added to or deleted from an object.

You need to use `$add` method to declare the property, so that it could be watched. Also if you want to remove a property, you need `$delete` method.

Comment: I have an array of objects, not strings. So your example code doesn't really make sense. Also, you're kind of wrong, because if I do `dudes[0].a = 'test'` that works. (changing `a` instead of `b`)

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar Well, I just noticed that I misunderstood your question. `a` is an existing proerty while `b` is not. You need `$add` to declare the property key first, so that it could be watched. Also call `$delete` if you want to remove a property.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that one in the docs. Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: this is not in the API, at least not anymore, therefor not a solution.

Comment: @KevinCompton Per OP's question, **if he hasn't updated vue.js**, then it is the solution. It just may not be the solution for the **latest** version.

Answer (score 2):

For the latest Vue version (2.2.0 at the time of this answer) this is what you should do:

Instead of `dudes[0].b = 'test'` just do:

```
Vue.set(dudes[0],'b','test');
```

from inside the method, or:

```
$set(dudes[0],'b','test')
```

from inside the view template (like in `@click="$set(dudes[0],'b','test')"`)